# form validation setting within the form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set form validation rules during form design itsef. Is it possible? In othercases if we change the field name we will have to open form_validation.php in config folder and change the fied name there also.Same thing happen for the other case also. So my desire is to set the form validation setting within the tag element like
. Is it possible?

Comment: can you explain why you would be changing field names of a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the rules in views/controllers like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
```

you cannot set the rules from within a html tag.